# Combining zero argument functions

Tags: python, function, if-statement

Is there a way to put the below code into one function? Or is there a way to make it less bulky?

```
def getf():
    while True:
        try:
            s = raw_input('> ')
            return float(s)
        except ValueError:
            print "Are you sure that's a number? Please enter a number"

def cats_and_people():
    print "Hello. We are in a crisis and need your help to set a number of animals!"
    print "First, let's set a number of cats!: "
    cats = float(getf())
    print "Now let's set a number of people!: "
    people = float(getf())
    if cats > people:
        print ("\nToo many cats! The World is doomed!").upper()
    else:
        print ("\nNot enough cats! The World is doomed!").upper()

cats_and_people()
```

Comment: What do you mean precisely by 'less bulky', and how merging these two functions to one will make it 'less bulky'?

Comment: thanks for the comment. I'm still a newbie in python and the answer from Ryan cleared some things for me. Now i understand that if i merge them together it will just be worse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eugene!

It's awesome that you're learning how to code!

In general, it is okay to have things in more than one function. Actually, you should focus on making as many functions as possible, as long as they're somewhat general-purpose!

This helps you structure the parts of your code which can help you in a lot of different ways, just a fraction of which are:

1) Each function is doing a specific thing. Allows you to better visualize what is happening!

2) This makes testing your functions easier, and when a test fails you know right away what part of your code needs work.

3) Easier to read!

There is nothing wrong with the way you're getting the user input. There are a few flaws in your code, but I see some good things as well:

1) You handled your exception properly.

2) Your variable names are fairly descriptive!

3) You're validating your input - awesome!

Some problems:

1) I think it is just a formatting error, but you need to indent the try block properly.

2) You're using float() twice on the user input. Not needed!

3) You don't need your parens on the last two print statements.

This is a great start. Keep at it! You'll have to get familiar with Python before worrying too much about the structure of your code. Once you're able to understand a lot of the Python API (know what functions you need to use to do certain operations) you'll be able to read popular libraries. Read the libraries you're interested in, and you'll learn about how they structure their code, their design patterns, etc.. which will add a lot to your tool-belt.

Good luck and have fun!

Answer (score 0):

if you are willing to give up the try block you could do something like:

```
def cats_and_ppl():
  print(...)
  cats = float(raw_input())
  print(...)
  ppl = float(raw_input())
  if ...:
  else..:
```

if you want to check that the input is indeed a number but you don't want to open another method, my suggestion is that you open a while loop and wait for acceptable input. something like:

```
while(x = raw_input()):
  if isinstance(x, float):
    break
```